# Constructor definition with a member initializer list

Tags: c++

I have some code that was given to me to finish but a few things are unfamiliar to me. First of all, what's the point of the member initializer in the first function?

```
class Circle {
private:
    double r;

public:
    Circle(double radius) : r(radius) {}

    double get_perimeter()
    {
        return 2*PI*r;
    }

    double get_radius()
    {
        return get_perimeter()/2*PI;
    }
};
```

and then in my `main()` function:

```
int main()
{
    double radius;
    cin >> radius;

    Circle c(radius);

    cout << c.get_radius << endl;


    return 0;
}
```

The `Circle c(radius);` line makes no sense to me. Can someone narrate me those few lines that I addressed?

Comment: You already seem to know the term _'member initializer'_, so what you're actually asking about?

Comment: Please re-read before marking as dupe.

Comment: No need to re-read, the answers in the dupe well explain what's going on. Besides `cout << c.get_radius << endl;` doesn't compile (should be `cout << c.get_radius() << endl;`), `Circle c(radius);` creates a new `Circle` instance and initializes the `radius` with the value just entered by the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Circle(double radius) : r(radius) {}
```

The point of the member initializer, `r(radius)`, is to initialize the member `r`, of course! This line defines the constructor of `Circle`. The constructor takes an argument of type `double` and the initialises the member `r` with that value.

```
Circle c(radius);
```

This declares a variable `c` with type `Circle` and passes `radius` to its constructor. Compare it to `std::string str("Foo");` or even `int x(5);` - these are all of the same form.